# Find an example of a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ for any $\delta > 0$ we have inclusion $[-1,1] \subseteq f([-\delta, \delta])$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Find an example of a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ for any
>   $\delta > 0$ we have inclusion $[-1,1] \subseteq f([-\delta, \delta])$

---

My idea:

$$f(x) = \sin(\frac{1}{x}) $$
but he works only for small interval near $0$, but not any $\delta > 0$

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Take some $n$ s.t. $\frac{1}{2 \pi n - \pi/2} < \delta$, then you have $[-1, 1] \subseteq f([\frac{1}{2 \pi n + \pi / 2}, \frac{1}{2\pi n - \pi / 2}]) \subseteq f([-\delta, \delta])$.

Comment: How about $f(x)=0$?

Comment: If it works for any small interval near $0$ (which does) then it will work for any $\delta > 0$.  If $\delta$ is big then the small intervals will be in it.

Comment: Thanks! I dont see about the obvious fact. Interval $[-\delta, \delta]$ is symmetric with respect to $0$:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"but he works only for small interval near 0, but not any δ>0"

If it works for a small interval near $0$, say $[-\delta_0, \delta_0]$ then it will work for every larger interval.  If $D > \delta_0$ and it works for $[-\delta_0, \delta_0]$ then it will work for $[-D, D]$ because $[\delta_0, \delta] \subset [-D,D]$

You function isn't defined for $x=0$ but if we extend it so $f(0) =\sqrt {97}$  your function will work.

For any $\delta > 0$ no matter how small (*OR* no matter how *large*) ther will alway be an $n$ so that $\delta > \frac 1{2\pi n} > \frac 1{2\pi n + 2\pi}$.  So

$[-1, 1] = f([\frac 1{2\pi n + 2\pi}, \frac 1{2\pi n}]\subset f([-\delta, \delta])$.